# Wamp Server not displaying image on page inside html tags?

Tags: php, html, image, wamp

why this works fine on wamp server:

```
<?php 
 //Let's generate a totally random string using md5 
    $md5_hash = md5(rand(0,999)); 
    //We don't need a 32 character long string so we trim it down to 5 
    $security_code = substr($md5_hash, 15, 5); 

    //Set the session to store the security code
    $_SESSION['security_code'] = $security_code;

    //Set the image width and height 
//    $im = imagecreate(97, 18);
    $im= @imagecreate(97, 18)
        or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");

    //white background and blue text
    $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 167, 167, 167);

    //Add randomly generated string in white to the image

    imagestring($im, 5, 27, 1, $security_code, $textcolor); 


    //Tell the browser what kind of file is come in 
    header("Content-Type: image/png"); 


    //Output the newly created image in jpeg format 
    imagepng($im); 

    //Free up resources
    imagedestroy($im); 
?>
```

but this, doesn't work (just add html tags) ?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
 //Let's generate a totally random string using md5 
    $md5_hash = md5(rand(0,999)); 
    //We don't need a 32 character long string so we trim it down to 5 
    $security_code = substr($md5_hash, 15, 5); 

    //Set the session to store the security code
    $_SESSION['security_code'] = $security_code;

    //Set the image width and height 
//    $im = imagecreate(97, 18);
    $im= @imagecreate(97, 18)
        or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");

    //white background and blue text
    $bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 167, 167, 167);

    //Add randomly generated string in white to the image

    imagestring($im, 5, 27, 1, $security_code, $textcolor); 


    //Tell the browser what kind of file is come in 
    header("Content-Type: image/png"); 


    //Output the newly created image in jpeg format 
    imagepng($im); 

    //Free up resources
    imagedestroy($im); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you tell me why inside html tags php code doesn't work on WAMP Server, but only php code works fine?

Comment: My guess is that you are going to have issues setting a header, since you've got things being output both before and after you set the headers.

Comment: That looks like an image dynamically generated for a capcha. It is designed to be called from an `img` tag on a page already delivered to the browser. Like `<img src="getimage.php">`. It does not need any HTML wrapped round it.